# Change floating tiny printer icon to a print button at top of cv

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Is it possible to change the small printer icon to a print button to be placed on the top right of the cv?

Currently the icon is tiny and hard to see on mobile devices and even difficult on the pc.

[image]

Be nice to use the current buttons that are used across jobs (big blue buttons with the actual word print).